# AndroidX supports 5.0 or lower?

Tags: android, androidx

I was developed with [AndroidX](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/) and it is a wonderful library, I run my demo app in my smartphone with Android 6, but I have a question, does AndroidX support Android 5.0 and lower?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the specific library, but on the whole the current set of `androidx` libraries support back to API Level 14 (Android 4.0).

Answer (score 0):

With Android Studio 3.2 and higher, you can quickly migrate an existing project to use AndroidX by selecting Refactor > Migrate to AndroidX from the menu bar.

Ref: [Migrate an existing project using Android Studio](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate#migrate)

You read more stuff from there base on your tpoic!